Is it possible to have the panel (in VSCode) sit in the center (top or bottom) but only as wide as one editor window?
Is it possible to have the panel (in VSCode) sit in the center (top or bottom) but only as wide as one of the editors so i can have a second editor open next to it thats the full height of the application window ?
So it would look something like the attached image.

Tried moving panel around with different alignments but none seem to be what i'd like.

Nope! Not possible

You could drag a file tab out into a separate window, then arrange the two windows side by side.

No. The panel and editor will be of the same width as open at the top or bottom.
